scss fonts files not laoded in webpack 5
The fonts which used in "styles/fonts" not loaded into app. the fonts imported into styles/base/fonts.scss file and fonts.scss imported into main.scss file directly.
But when running app in development mode the fonts not loaded correctly. files content attached into my question.
I'm appreciate for helping me to solve this issue.
fonts.scss
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url("../fonts/IRANSansWeb/IRANSansWeb_Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}

webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const PACKAGE = require('./package.json');
const version = PACKAGE.version;

module.exports = (_, argv) => {
  const { mode, env:{TYPE: type} } = argv;
  const config = {
    devServer: {
      compress: true,
      client: {
        overlay: false,
      },
     
      // https: true,
      // historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-mic/dist'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-icons/*'),

          ],
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { loose: true }], '@babel/preset-react'],
              plugins: [
                'babel-plugin-styled-components',
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
                [
                  '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
                  {
                    legacy: true,
                  },
                ],
                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
                ['@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods', { loose: true }],
                ['@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object', { loose: true }],
                [
                  '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                  {
                    regenerator: true,
                  },
                ],
                [
                  '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
                  {
                    runtime: 'automatic',
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'html-loader',
              options: { minimize: true },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            'style-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: {
                  localIdentName: mode === 'production' ? '[hash:config64:5]' : '[local]',
                  getLocalIdent: (loaderContext, _, localName) => {
                    if (mode === 'production') {
                      return loaderContext.resourcePath.includes('ModalMedia') ||
                        loaderContext.resourcePath.includes('emoji') ||
                        localName.includes('leaflet') ||
                        localName.includes('Toastify') ||
                        localName.includes('react-tabs') ||
                        localName.includes('rmdp')
                        ? localName
                        : null;
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            'resolve-url-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              // include: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles')],
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                // additionalData: '@import "./variables.scss";',
                additionalData: '@import "variables";',
                sassOptions: {
                  includePaths: [__dirname, './src/styles'],
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|mp3)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                limit: 1000000,
                name: 'assets/[hash].[ext]'
              }
            },
          ],
        },
        
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: './index.html',
        filename: './index.html',
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].css',
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
      }),
      // new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      //   'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed),
      // }),
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.wasm'],
      alias: {
        '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles'),
        '@actions': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/actions'),
        '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utils'),
        '@reducers': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/reducers'),
        '@services': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/services'),
        '@constants': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/constants'),
        '@icons': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/icons'),
      },
      fallback: {
        path: false,
        buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
        tls: false,
        os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
        assert: require.resolve('assert'),
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
        'process/browser': require.resolve('process/browser'),
      },
    },
  };

  //IF MODE IS PRODUCTION
  if (mode === 'production') {
    if (type !== 'old-school') {
      config.externals = [
        {
          react: {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react',
          },
          'react-dom': {
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom',
          },
        },
      ];
    }
    config.output = {
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      filename: type === 'old-school' ? 'index-old-school.js' : `index-${version}.js`,
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      // library: 'lib',
      library: 'index',
      hashFunction: 'xxhash64',
    };
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: 'src/app/pwa/sw.js',
            to: '',
          },
          {
            from: 'src/app/pwa/icons',
            to: 'icons',
          },
          {
            from: 'styles/fonts/**/*',
            toType: 'dir',
          },
          {
            from: 'styles/images/**/*',
            toType: 'dir',
          },
        ],
      })
    );
  } else {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
  }

  return config;
};



files structure:
src
 - styles
    - base
       fonts.scss
    - fonts
       - IRANSansWeb
           IRANSansWeb_Bold.ttf
    main.scss

